# find the position of the cursor where user have clicked and display one div where user have clicked

Tags: javascript, mootools1.2

I want to determine the position of the cursor where user have clicked.

And display one div at bottom side of the page where user have clicked.

For example on stack over flow home page if some one click on the logo.

Then the div should be displayed at the bottom position of the logo.

Same way if i click on the bottom link then that div should be displayed at the bottom portion of the page.

I am using mootools as my JS framework. But any JavaScript code will be helpful for me.

Hope this is clear to all.

Thanks in advance
Avinash

Answer (score 1):

```
<head>
</script>        
function mouseX(evt) 
{
    if (evt.pageX) return evt.pageX;
    else if (evt.clientX)
        return evt.clientX + (document.documentElement.scrollLeft ? document.documentElement.scrollLeft : document.body.scrollLeft);
    else return null;
}
function mouseY(evt) 
{
    if (evt.pageY) return evt.pageY;
    else if (evt.clientY)
        return evt.clientY + (document.documentElement.scrollTop ? document.documentElement.scrollTop :  document.body.scrollTop);
    else return null;
}
function clicked(evt)
{
    if(typeof evt == 'undefined')
    evt = window.event;
    alert("X = "+ mouseX(evt) + " Y= " + mouseY(evt);

}
</script></head>
<body onclick="clicked()"></body>
```

You can use simply the `window.event.x, window.event.y` but this is a more stable & reliable method of getting positions..

[ instead of alert, u'll be changing the `divElement.style.left ,  divElement.style.top`.. make sure the div's `position`(in style) is `absolute`. ]

Comment: i have tried it but its displaying below error: evt is undefined

Answer (score 0):

With prototype is pretty simple:

```
document.observe('click', function(e) {
    $('YourDivId').setStyle({
        'left': e.clientX, 
        'top': e.clientY
    }).show();
});
```

All you need to do now is create a html DIV on your body with "display: none" and "position: absolute;" and the content you want.